# デバッグモード実行について

Tags: spring

surface laptopPCでプログラミングを行う時に、F6を押してデバッグ実行しようとしたら、音量を上げることになってしまいました。ちなみに開発ツールはspring tool suite です。どうしたらいいでしょうか、誠に恐縮ですがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

キーボードの右下の方に`fn`と書かれたボタンがないでしょうか？
その`fn`を押しながらファンクションキーを押下することで、`F1`~`F12`等のファンクションキーになります。
`fn`キーはトグル式になっていて、`fn`が押され続けてロックされている状態かどうかは`fn`キーの右上のLEDが点灯しているかどうかで判断出来るそうです。